# Rock,Paper,Scissors but always player 1 wins

Tags: python

I made this rock-paper-scissors game in Python, and I expected it to make player 1 or player 2 win according to their choice during the prompt. However, it always shows that player 1 has won. How do I make player 2 win in situations where they are supposed to win according to standard rock-paper-scissors rules?

Sorry for the silly question if this is one, I am a beginner.

```
print("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors!")
print("Use R for Rock , P for Paper and S for Scissors")
print()
n = input("Do you want name? (Y/N) :")
if n == "yes" or n == "Yes" or n == "Y" or n == "y":
  p1n = input("Name for player 1? :")
  p2n = input("Name for player 2? :")
  name = True
else:
  name = False
from getpass import getpass as input
p1=input("What do you choose?(R,P or S)(p1): ")
p2=input("What do you choose?(R,P or S)(p2): ")
if p1 == "paper" or p1 == "Paper" or p1 == "p" or p1 == "P" and p2 == "rock" or p2 == "Rock" or p2 == "r" or p2 == "R":
  print("Player 1 has won! GG!")
  if name == True:
    print(p1n,"has won! GG!")
elif p1 == "rock" or p1 == "Rock" or p1 == "r" or p1 == "R" and p2 == "scissors" or p2 == "Scissors" or p2 == "s" or p2 == "S":
  print("Player 1 has won! GG!")
  if name == True:
    print(p1n,"has won! GG!")
elif p1 == "scissors" or p1 == "Scissors" or p1 == "s" or p1 == "S" and p2 == "paper" or p2 == "Paper" or p2 == "p" or p2 == "P":
  print("Player 1 has won! GG!")
  if name == True:
    print(p1n,"has won! GG!")
elif p1 == "rock" or p1 == "Rock" or p1 == "r" or p1 == "R" and p2 == "rock" or p2 == "Rock" or p2 == "r" or p2 == "R":
  print("Its a tie! LOL !")
elif p1 == "paper" or p1 == "Paper" or p1 == "p" or p1 == "P" and p2 == "paper" or p2 == "Paper" or p2 == "p" or p2 == "P":
  print("Its a tie! LOL !")
elif p1 == "scissors" or p1 == "Scissors" or p1 == "s" or p1 == "S" and p2 == "scissors" or p2 == "Scissors" or p2 == "s" or p2 == "S":
  print("Its a tie! LOL !")
elif p2 == "rock" or p2 == "Rock" or p2 == "r" or p2 == "R" and p1 == "scissors" or p1 == "Scissors" or p1 == "s" or p1 == "S":
  print("Player 2 has won! Well Played!")
  if name == True:
    print(p2n,"has won! Well Played!")
elif p2 == "paper" or p2 == "Paper" or p2 == "p" or p2 == "P" and p1 == "rock" or p1 == "Rock" or p1 == "r" or p1 == "R":
  print("Player 2 has won! Well Played!")
  if name == True:
    print(p2n,"has won! Well Played!")
elif p2 == "scissors" or p2 == "Scissors" or p2 == "s" or p2 == "S" and p1 == "paper" or p1 == "Paper" or p1 == "p" or p1 == "P":
  print("Player 2 has won! Well Played!")
  if name == True:
    print(p2n,"has won! Well Played!")
else:
  print("Don't trick me dumbo!(And if u put scissor intead of scissors then its not my fault!)")
```

Comment: `a or b and c or d` without parentheses means `a or (b and c) or d`. If you want logic like `(a or b) and (c or d)` then you need to include the parentheses. This is the result of `and` having higher precedence than `or`: see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: As a suggestion, you can use something like `if p1.lower() in ('s', 'scissors')` to avoid multiple checks.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych - or even better, turn all this stuff into an enum, and just have the user input the corresponding value. `if p1 == Choices.Scissors: ...`

Comment: @OneMadGypsy That's the next level :) I'd make a class with the overridden `__gte__` and `__eq__`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with your code is in the logic of the `if-elif` statements. The conditions inside each `if-elif` statement need to be correctly grouped with **parentheses**, otherwise the Python interpreter doesn't interpret them as you might expect.

**The `and` operator has higher precedence than the `or` operator in Python**. This means that your conditions are being interpreted in a way that you didn't intend.

For instance, let's consider the condition:

```py
p1 == "paper" or p1 == "Paper" or p1 == "p" or p1 == "P" and p2 == "rock" or p2 == "Rock" or p2 == "r" or p2 == "R"
```

This is being interpreted as:

```py
p1 == "paper" or p1 == "Paper" or p1 == "p" or (p1 == "P" and p2 == "rock") or p2 == "Rock" or p2 == "r" or p2 == "R"
```

which means if p1 equals "P", and p2 equals "rock", or if p1 equals "paper", "Paper", or "p", regardless of what p2 is, the condition will evaluate to True. This is why Player 1 seems to always win.

You need to use parentheses to ensure that the condition is evaluated as you expect:

```py
(p1 == "paper" or p1 == "Paper" or p1 == "p" or p1 == "P") and (p2 == "rock" or p2 == "Rock" or p2 == "r" or p2 == "R")
```

Now this condition will only evaluate to True if Player 1 selects paper and Player 2 selects rock.

Apply the same concept to the other conditions in your if-elif statements to correct the game logic.

Answer (score 1):

Make your life easier and avoid buggy comparisons against multiple values altogether:

```
beats = {"r": "s", "s": "p", "p": "r"}
# ...
n = input("Do you want name? (Y/N) :")
if n.lower()[0] == "y":
    p1n = input("Name for player 1? :")
    p2n = input("Name for player 2? :")
else:
    p1n = "Player 1"
    p2n = "Player 2"
# ...
p1 = p1.lower()[0]
p2 = p2.lower()[0]

if p1 == p2:
    print("Its a tie! LOL !")
elif beats.get(p1) == p2:
    print(f"{p1n} has won! Well Played!")
elif beats.get(p2) == p1:
    print(f"{p2n} has won! Well Played!")
else:
    # random insult for providing nonsensical input
```

Comment: It would be good to add a check of the input, otherwise "**S**uperman" and "**S**piderman" would be a tie as well ;)

Comment: That's fine. They both count for scissors =) this is a robust program

Comment: I didn't understand but guess it works

Comment: Name error p1 is not defined

Comment: @ToxicGamer329 Of course, you have leave in your original lines where you read p1, p2 from user input. That is meant by the `# ...`  comment lines